# What is the formula for creating an n-dimensional grid from a 1-dimensional loop?

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to create a 3D grid of `Node` types (a custom data-type).

To create a 2D grid, I usually use this formula:
where `i` is the current iteration in 1D loop, and `gridsize` is size of one axis of grid

```
x = i % gridsize,  
y = floor(i / gridsize)
```

For example, in Python:

```
from math import floor

grid = list()
gridsize = 3       # 3x3 grid

for i in range(gridsize**2):
    x = i % gridsize
    y = floor(i / gridsize)
    grid.append( Node(x, y) )
```

How can I alter this formula to find `x`, `y`, and `z` coordinates for a 3D grid, and is there a general rule for finding coordinates for nD grids?

Comment: The usual way to implement n-dimensional lists in Python is to have a list of lists of lists...of a list of values (i.e. nested lists), but that doesn't appear to be the way you are storing the `Node`s (i.e. just one long list) — so what is the point of determining what their coordinates *would be* if you had stored them the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afer writing out a table of `x`, `y` and `z` values for a 3x3x3 grid, I figured this out:

For a **cubic** 3D¹ grid

```
x = i % gs
y = floor(i / gs) % gs
z = floor(i / gs²)
```

where `i` is the current iteration, and `gs` is length of one axis.

With a bit of extrapolation, here's a formula<sup>2</sup> for an nD grid:
`cn = floor(i / gsn-1) % gs`
For example:

```
x = floor( i / gs⁰ ) % gs    # 1D
y = floor( i / gs¹ ) % gs    # 2D 
z = floor( i / gs² ) % gs    # 3D 
a = floor( i / gs³ ) % gs    # 4D
```

etc.

**NOTE:**

1. The `x` value can be simplified to `i % gs` because
   `i/gs0 % gs` => `i/1 % gs` => `i % gs`. Likewise, we can remove the `% gs` from the calculation of the `z` value, because the loop should never go over `gs3`
2. This formula only works for **cubic** grids (ie. grids whose axes all have the same number of points on them - 2x2x2x2, 5x5x5, etc.). 3x4x5 grids, for example, require a different formula.

Answer (score 2):

`x` ticks up the fastest, incrementing by 1 every time `i` increments, and wraps around when it reaches `gridsize`:

```
x = i % gridsize
```

`y` ticks up more slowly, incrementing by 1 every time `i` increases by `gridsize`, but also wraps around when it reaches `gridsize`:

```
y = (i // gridsize) % gridsize
```

`z` ticks up the slowest, incrementing by 1 every time `i` increases by `gridsize**2`, and we don't need it to wrap around:

```
z = i // gridsize**2
```

We can generalize this:

```
x = (i // gridsize**0) % gridsize
y = (i // gridsize**1) % gridsize
z = (i // gridsize**2) % gridsize
```

I'm sure you see the pattern here.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a formula but just this:

```
r = range(gridsize)
grid = [Node(x, y, z) for z in r for y in r for x in r]
```

Or with an arbitrary dimension, using `itertools.product`:

```
grid = [Node(*p[::-1]) for p in product(range(gridsize), repeat=griddim)]
```

If you don't mind the order of the nodes, you can leave out the `[::-1]` or also use `itertools.starmap`:

```
grid = list(starmap(Node, product(range(gridsize), repeat=griddim)))
```